# What to do for code formatting bug on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, code-formatting

Looks like SO's code formatting has a bug and it's ignoring first few lines no matter what I do. Not sure who to contact but if you know the solution or can tell how to forward to SO's developers that would be great.

Answer that has bad code formatting bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23103932/207661

Comment: That is because there is a bullet list before it. That screws the markup.

Comment: Due to bullets it is escaping spaces so you need to add `-----` in between of the bullets and code. and this will format properly.

Comment: So, the solution seems to be 8 spaces instead of 4.

Comment: Only if you want it to be part of the list @PatrickHofman. Not if it's supposed to come after.

Comment: @Bart: good point. Then it still might be a bug.

Comment: @Patrick: there is no bug, this is how the stuff is designed to work. If you don't want a horizontal bar, you can use a `<!-- -->` thingy instead to break out of the list.

Comment: So we can close this as 'by design'?

Comment: May be silly question: why markdown parser can't figure out end of list? It seems reasonable that if there is two new lines, it should mark the end of the list. Adding arbitrary comment tag isn't obvious at all.